# select a label from a list with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, label

I want to select or write the desired option "Leads " from the following code:
´´´

Leads      Leads   Prospecting   Prospecting Alimentación y Gran Consumo   Prospecting Textil y Moda   Prospecting Viajes y Turismo    No matches found. Consider changing the search query.   No pipelines found

´´´

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Also please share your code so far, the challenge you face with it and any error you experience  :-)

Comment: You're saying your button is part of a dropdown list and you want to be able select different values?  - if you can share the relevant html source instead of a cropped images we can see the options available and help you with the problem  :-)

Comment: Sorry, I can´t copy the html code

Comment: can you copy if you try: in chrome, Right click -> View Page Source

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn´t keep the html format when pasting on stackoverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
driver.get("https://baud.teamwork.com/launchpad/login?continue=%2Fcrm")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#loginemail"))).send_keys("usernaame")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#loginpassword"))).send_keys("pwd")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("w-button--blue").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//div//div//header//div[1]//div[1]//button[1]"))).click()
```

Comment: It is giving me this error: 
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Comment: Also I would like to post one of the options the element is giving me

Comment: Can you pleaase share your email and password. I am unable to login with above credential also failed to login with my google details

Comment: I have updated my code. its clicking on the Leads now

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. How to select one of the options from that clickable?

Answer (score 1):

For python:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).get_attribute('text')
```

Comment: this is not working:  
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='Change pipeline']").get_attribute('Leads')

Comment: What I want is to post "Leads" and navigate there, not getting the options

Comment: By "post leads" do you mean click the button?

Comment: Yes, click the option "Leads" it is not a button, is a list eith different options